# Loading csv with unicode utf-8 into elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch

i am trying to load csv file into elasticsearch using the code below. When running the code no failure is shown and once loading is done i try to access data in the localhost:9200 but i somehow cant which means loading did not work. my csv data is saved as utf8 csv.So i saved it as csv only and i had to change the encoding in the code below to 'latin-1' otherwise i receive failure and this option worked but the problem is that any chinese or japanese sentences in the data are turning to be symbols and this is not my target. Any ideas how to load utf8 csv into elasticsearch. I tried 'import codecs' but did not help.

```
import csv
with open('my_data.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DirectReader(f,delimiter = ';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        es.index(index = 'my_index', body = row, ignore = 400)
```

Comment: Share a few lines of that csv please.

Comment: thanks for the comment. i solved the problem changing "utf-8" to "utf-8-sig" in the code. I dont know why is this solving the problem but at least its working now. Thanks